# Check CMOS voltage from inside OS

Tags: ntp, cmos, clock, voltage, timedrift

I was recently diagnosing a time drift issue for a client located in a different city.
Their workstations were having issues accessing the **Windows 2019 server** due to this drift.

Based on the age of the device, my initial instinct was a dying CMOS battery. I thought maybe *AIDA64* might provide those details, but it did not.
Another user on here recommended using a program called *hwinfo*, which after trying on my own device, I found works great, but being unable to install unapproved software on this device, I was unable to use it for my purposes..

SOO.. I first changed the time in the GUI, then continued my other tasks. Over that 1 hour, the clock again drifted by almost 1 min.
..CMOS
I ran some cmds, mostly w32tm and saw CMOS as the clock source, but being very far away from the server, and not trusting anyone onsite to change the battery, I reassigned the source to pool.ntp.org and changed related settings, with help from this walk-thru:
**https://icookservers.blog/2014/09/12/windows-ntp-server-cookbook/**

I cannot verify the voltage, but based on

1. the observed drift over 1hr
2. reg entry: **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Config\AnnounceFlags** set to 10 (this tells the server to sync time to local CMOS clock)

3.the results from **w32tm /query /source** (Local CMOS clock)

4.the results from **w32tm /query /status /verbose** (the computer did not resync because no time data was available)

5.Buncha other things
it seemed undeniable that all configs pointed to be dependent upon a failing source...

***Questions: how reliably will this work as a workaround to prevent this time drift and does anyone know any methods using CMD or PowShell or built in utilities that will provide a V+ reading on the battery?***

If it is not a dying CMOS, and if it wasnt caused by the default windows time server settings, what else can I do to figure out the cause?

I personally would love an on-the-clock, out of town trip to change a small cell battery as much as the client would hate it, but in the meantime...

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking CMOS battery without going into the BIOS](https://superuser.com/questions/1816278/checking-cmos-battery-without-going-into-the-bios)

Comment: harrymc  I referenced that post before posting this one, and no it does not. My experience was about the same as the OPs in that link.

Comment: That post was helpful though, and is where i discovered the freeware hwinfo, which when i used it on a different computer, did provide a measure on the CMOS voltage.

Comment: In that post, which basically asks the same question I am, their issue was hours of forward drift and I assume they could install hwinfo on their device. 
I am not permitted to install 3rd party software on this device.. if i was then hwinfo would have solved my problem.

Comment: *Caveat:* HWiNFO and HWiNFO 64 can report only what the PC makes available. On the machine I'm using now, CMOS battery voltage is *not* shown (HWiNFO v. 7.72).

Comment: The client has pretty much ruled out any methods that would allow you to diagnose or fix the problem. I would simply set up a script that runs `w32tm /resync` every half hour and tell them that if the battery *is* failing then that server may come up in an odd state with wrong CMOS settings in the event of a power cut.